# select2 is in my source code but does not want to work

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, laravel-5.4

[image]Select2 is in my source code but for some reason does not want to work.
Here is a link to my jsfiddle [Select2 not working](https://jsfiddle.net/amidabrian54/2a11fqhp/)

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
          <script>
          $('.select2-multi').select2();

          </script>
```

Comment: can you show me your HTML/

Comment: Its jsfiddle link.

Comment: I have had few issues trying to get this work.  In the end, I had to hard code the HTML on another page which uses it.  Don't want to have to do that every time.

Comment: Maybe I will show you an image of what I have.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zkr0b4vc/

Comment: Your src tag for jquery is missing `https:`.  In addition, select2 v4 requires at least jQuery v1.7.2

Answer (score 0):

```
<select class="form-control select2-multi" multiple="multiple name="category_id">
```

you should indicate the class

here is the working fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/zkr0b4vc/

Comment: That is what I have done `{{ Form::select('schools[]', $schools, null, ['class' => 'form-control select2-multi', 'multiple' => 'multiple']) }}`

Comment: add `multiple="multiple"`

Comment: instead of `'multiple' => 'multiple'`?

Comment: oh can you inspect element? see if there's a multiple="multiple"

Comment: Yes there is multiple="multiple"

Comment: I am not sure that is the right one.  It has Create a Member at the top.

Comment: Can you please look at this one.  This should be the right one. https://jsfiddle.net/amidabrian54/0me0hd3o/

Comment: your jquery seems outdated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147171/discussion-between-altbrian-and-clarkoy).